# grep and cut to print every nth line (Unix)

Tags: unix, grep, cut

Is there a way to use grep and cut in a pipeline to print only nth line of an input?

I know this can be done with sed but I was curious if this was possible with grep ?

Comment: it is more suited for sed/awk... why do you want to use grep for this? it will also help if you post sample input/output so that it might give more detail if your explanation has missed something, like why do you mention cut?

Comment: No ...........................................